# How to get dynamically changing Key's value in Json using jackson in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

below is my json string parsing using jackson using java , in which the storage array values  will be dynamically changing based on the region , US, UK or any region. how to handle these objects

```
{
"serviceType": {
    "US - Northern California 1": [
      {
        "serviceName": "Virtual Private Cloud",
        "tenantType": "VP",
        "licenseType": "EDUCATIONAL",
        "description": "Virtual Private Cloud",
        "defaultFlag": "N",
        "tooltip": "",
        "storage": [
          {
            "ACC STORAGE": {
              "storageName": "SSD Accelerated Storage",
              "terms": [
                [
                  "12 months",
                  "12_MTH",
                  [
                    "Prepaid",
                    "Monthly"
                  ],
                  "N"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "US - New Jersey 1": [
      {
        "serviceName": "Air Dedicated Cloud",
        "tenantType": "DCP",
        "licenseType": "EDUCATIONAL",
        "description": "Air Dedicated Cloud",
        "defaultFlag": "N",
        "tooltip": "",
        "storage": [
          {
            "STD STORAGE": {
              "storageName": "Standard Storage",
              "terms": [
                [
                  "12 months",
                  "12_MTH",
                  [
                    "Monthly",
                    "Prepaid"
                  ]
              ]
            ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
        ]

    }
}
```

My question is: **how do I access the content of "storage" since "ACC STORAGE", "STD STORAGE", etc are all dynamic values?**

```
  public class ServiceType 
{
    @JsonProperty("US - Northern California 1")
    public List<serviceTypes> USNorthernCalifornia1;
    @JsonProperty("US - New Jersey 1")
    public List<serviceTypes> uSNewJersey1;

     //getters and setters
}

public class serviceTypes
{
   public class serviceTypes 
{
    @JsonProperty("serviceName")
    public String serviceName;
    @JsonProperty("tenantType")
    public String tenantType;
    @JsonProperty("licenseType")
    public String licenseType;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    public String description;
    @JsonProperty("defaultFlag")
    public String defaultFlag;
    @JsonProperty("tooltip")
    public String tooltip;
    @JsonProperty("storage")
    public List<Storage> storage = new ArrayList<Storage>();
 //getters and setters
}

public class storage
{

}
```

**the  class storage left blank as i am confused wht to declare as the values will dynamically change**

Please help me . thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Usually this means that some properties use basic `Map` to contain values (where keys can be arbitrary Strings), instead of only using POJOs. `Map` values can still be POJOs, as well as `Map`s or `List`s.

Answer (score 0):

Just go on and write the Storage class. Jackson will map the values automatically into your storage List via the Objectmapper.

One solution might be inheritance. You need multiple  classes with different "IDs" but same properties.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but still i am confused to to proceed to create the claases as u mentioned above  as they names - "ACC STORAGE", "STD STORAGE", etc are all dynamic values , but  storage name ,terms can be common for them that i have created a class  as below  public class stname
{
        @JsonProperty("storageName")
 public String storageName;
 @JsonProperty("terms")
 public List<List<String>> terms = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
 
       getters and setters

 

public class Storage extends stname
{

}  how to implement those here can u giude me with a sample example

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a `Map`.

```
public class ServiceTypes {

    private List<Map<String, Storage>> storage;

    // other fields ommited
}
```

Where the `Storage` class would now become:

```
public class ServiceTypes {

    private String storageName;

    // etc
}
```

I´ve changed the visibility of the fields to `private`, you need the corresponding getters and setters.